# I can't find out what is wrong with my background

Tags: html, css

So I want to set the file wallpaper.png as the backgound of the page, the image is in the same folder with the html and css files.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheethome" href="stylesheethome.css"/>
    <title>Prism</title>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

And the css:

```
    body {
    background-image: url("wallpaper.png");
}
```

Comment: its working fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/rh31oL9d/

Answer (score 1):

the problemi is with this-

```
rel="stylesheethome
```

change it to--

`stylesheet...`  hope this works..

After changing it is working I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Your body is empty, that's the same for zero pixel height. You can try like this:

```
 html, body { 
     height: 100%;
 }
```

Good luck.

Comment: this is not the reason check this http://jsfiddle.net/rh31oL9d/ .. body has no element like in question

Comment: With the data that the user give us we can't help him better. If the image is in same folder that css and html, he is making another thing that he doesn't tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `stylesheet` for `rel` in your `<link>` and check your file names.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheethome.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I changed the rel attribute value from stylesheethome to stylesheet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheethome.css"/>
    <title>Prism</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

stylesheethome is not a valid rel attribute value.
Hope this helps.